# Subtract tuple of tuples from a tuple in Python?

Tags: python, tuples

I have a tuple of tuples:

```
nums = ((4, 5, 6), (5, 6, 7), (2, 3))
```

Now I want to create a similar structure in which each number is subtracted from a 'baseline' number. The baseline numbers for the tuples are:

```
baselines = (1, 0.5, 3)
```

So the structure I want would be:

```
# want: diffs = ((3, 4, 5), (4.5, 5.5, 6.5), (-1, 0))
```

where we have:

```
diffs[0] = [x - baselines[0] for x in nums[0]]
diffs[1] = [x - baselines[1] for x in nums[1]]
# etc.
```

How can I do this elegantly in Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `zip` with a generator expression:

```
In [66]: nums = ((4, 5, 6), (5, 6, 7), (2, 3))

In [67]: baselines = (1, 0.5, 3)

In [68]: tuple( tuple( val-y for val in x ) for x,y in zip (nums,baselines ))
Out[68]: ((3, 4, 5), (4.5, 5.5, 6.5), (-1, 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> [[x-baselines[i] for x in nums[i]] for i in range(3)]
[[3, 4, 5], [4.5, 5.5, 6.5], [-1, 0]]
```

You can make it tuples like so

```
>>> tuple(tuple(x-baselines[i] for x in nums[i]) for i in range(3))
((3, 4, 5), (4.5, 5.5, 6.5), (-1, 0))
```